# How to add audio to a chat room in a JavaFx 2.0 application

Tags: java, javafx-2

Im trying to add the ability to have audio in my site's chat rooms so the users can talk to each other. How can I get a start on that? All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific JavaFX support for that task. You can use any exicting java approach:

- there is several service providers which provides web-service you can include in your application for money: http://www.chatessentials.com/main/, http://www.smaxe.com/applet.jsf?id=rtmp-audio-chat (just googled for a minute)
- also there is code examples, but they requires a lot work to build a real application from them. E.g. http://javasolution.blogspot.com/2007/04/voice-chat-using-java.html